# CGImage.cropping(to:) is flipped on OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I'm finding that `CGImage.cropping(to:)` treats the rectangle specified using an origin at the top left (with increasing Y going downward) instead of bottom left (with increasing Y going upward). This is particularly odd, since `CGImage` isn't oriented that way by default and because when applying a mask this is not the case. Please note this has nothing to do with `UIImage` and orientation -- this is OS X-specific.

I'm submitting this as a question, but this is more of an observation. There is much more info on iOS in Stack Overflow on Core Graphics than OS X, and Apple's documentation on cropping doesn't explain this.

Below is code that draws the lower right quadrant of the image, whereas the expectation is that it would draw the upper right quadrant.

```
func getImage(_ url: CFURL) -> CGImage? {
    guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, nil) else { return nil }

    guard let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) else {
        let imageSourceStatus = CGImageSourceGetStatus(imageSource)
        Swift.print("image nil, Image Source Status = \(imageSourceStatus)")
        return nil
    }
    return image
}

func northeastQuadrant(fromImage: CGImage) -> CGRect {
    let w = CGFloat(fromImage.width)
    let h = CGFloat(fromImage.height)
    let bottomleft = CGPoint(x: w/2.0, y: h/2.0)
    return CGRect(x: bottomleft.x, y: bottomleft.y, width: w/2.0, height: h/2.0)
}

func southwestQuadrant(fromImage: CGImage) -> CGRect {
    let w = CGFloat(fromImage.width)
    let h = CGFloat(fromImage.height)
    return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: w/2.0, height: h/2.0)
}

class CGImageView: NSView {
    func setImage() {
        let url = CFURLCreateWithString(nil, "file:////Users/erickampman/Documents/FractIFS/Demonic%20Scarecrows.tiff" as CFString, nil)

        let img = getImage(url!)
        let quad = northeastQuadrant(fromImage: img!)
//        let quad = southwestQuadrant(fromImage: img!)
        image = img!.cropping(to: quad)
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        if nil == image {
            Swift.print("Calling setImage")
            setImage()
        }

        guard let image = self.image else {
            Swift.print("Nil image!")
            return
        }
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        guard let cgContext = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else { return }
        Swift.print("ctx transform: \(cgContext.ctm)")
        cgContext.saveGState();
        cgContext.draw(image, in: self.bounds, byTiling: false)
        cgContext.restoreGState();
    }

    var image: CGImage?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [doc for `croppingToRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1454683-cropping) talks about counting pixels:

> - The rect is then intersected with a rectangle whose origin is (0,0)...
> - The pixels within the resulting rectangle are read, treating the first pixel within the rectangle...
>
> If W and H are the width and height of image, respectively, then the point (0,0) corresponds to the first pixel of the image data. The point (W–1, 0) is the last pixel...

so it seems like the subimage is calculated in a sort of "raster coordinate space" rather than using a coordinate space that corresponds to any other element.